# Debug php on production, what configuration is used and where is the log

Tags: php, apache, debugging, symfony, production

I'm getting an error on production server but am unable to figure out what it is. Blank page with 500 response code isn't very helpful and adding ini_set to output the error doesn't help because I'm using Symfony and that has another way of dealing with errors that will take me 2 days to figure out.

Apache logs php errors and php is supposed to log php errors, phpinfo tells me that log_errors is on and error_log is /var/log/php.log. That file contains a warning of 1.5 years ago so I guess Symfony is messing things up somewhere.

Try Apache/httpd log. After figuring out what config files are used and where the log is I can't find anything in there after getting a 500 error. Does it take a while before that gets written?

Stuck here and not sure how to figure out what it is that's causing the error. Are there any other options? I guess Symfony should log it somewhere but Symfony/app/logs is empty, there was a very large dev.log there but after renaming it it isn't created again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the file that you have set PHP to log to in the php.ini file is in the group for which the http server runs as. Typically this user is www-data

```
chown /var/log/php_errors.log root::www-data
chmod 664 /var/log/php_errors.log

sudo apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was written to the php error log because the permissions were set wrong and user running httpd could not write to it.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.